# Why is pfSense giving me incorrect memory usage when VirtIO memory ballooning is used?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kvm, pfsense, libvirt

I am running pfSense as a KVM/libvirt guest. When I configure `memory` and `currentMemory` both to 2048 MB the pfSense dashboard shows ~2GB of ram and 18% utilization. If I set `memory` to 2048 MB and `currentMemory` to 4096 MB (to make use of memory ballooning) the pfSense dashboard shows ~4GB of ram and 62% utilization. This makes absolutely no sense that pfSense would actually be using this much memory, so it must be incorrect. Is this a known bug and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's just [how "memory ballooning" works](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/virtio-balloon/). The host cannot actually take away RAM from a running system, so instead the guest's balloon driver *consumes* the amount of guest RAM that it wants to return to the host. In other words, the balloon inflates inwards, not outwards.

For example, in your case, the VM in fact *always* has 4096 MB of memory, but the *other* 2048 MB are automatically consumed by the virtio_balloon driver (or its FreeBSD equivalent) which lets the host know that it doesn't need to allocate that amount of physical RAM yet. The result is that instead of "x out of 2048 MB" usage, you'll see "x+2048 out of 4096 MB".

(On Linux, when the VM needs more memory, it uses [pressure notifications](https://marc.info/?l=kvm&m=138988948715638&w=2) to ask the balloon driver to give up some of the reserved memory, which it does after asking the host to actually allocate it.)

So guest tools which report memory usage must be aware of balloon drivers (e.g. by looking at `sysctl dev.vtballoon.0.current` in pfSense's www/system_advanced_misc.inc file) – if they aren't, then they'll always see the additional memory as "used". From searching various forums, it seems to be a very common problem with pfSense and OPNsense dashboards not doing this correctly. (There also seems to be an almost complete lack of documentation for this driver on BSDs, too.)